# Run separated cucumber files chained

Tags: cucumber, appium

I am studying Appium with cucumber

And I have different cucumber scenarios, for example:

login.feature with LoginSteps.java and Login.java to do actions with the app

I need to add more scenarios and I want to make different files like help.feature, payment.feature, etc.

All these scenarios need to do a login before, so, they need to get LoginSteps before to do HelpSteps

```
LoginSteps -> HelpSteps
LoginSteps -> PaymentSteps
...
```

What is the best way or the best architecture to build this kind of project?

Any reference is welcome.

Comment: You can use cucumber hooks.

Comment: Thanks, I will find information about that, I know the logic of the hooks, for example, I know how to make a "tear down", with before and after. But I don't know how to chain. Thanks Agaian